# how to do git-pull without getting untracked files updated

Tags: git, github

I have untracked few files via my `.gitignore` Somebody have edited those untracked files.

Now pulling from origin master throw errors saying untracked files will be overwritten by merge. please move or remove them before you can merge. I don't want my untracked files to get updated nor i want them to get deleted from hard disk.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else has decided that there should be checked in files with the same names as your untracked files. This is not a technology problem, this is a human problem. You have to talk to the person(s) who checked in these file(s) and settle the business one way or the other.

If the two of you decide that the files should not have been checked in, you will need to make another clone and use it to revert their checkin and then pull into your current clone. If you decide the other way, well, then you'll be renaming files or something.

Comment: actually someone else removed those file name from .gitignore. then edited those files and pushed to remote repo. is thr any way to pull from remote repo without getting change on those files

Comment: You just repeated what I typed. No, you can't ask git to prefer untracked files and pull. You'll have to make another clone, undo the unwanted adds, commit that, and pull the results to your main workspace.